# To control Philips Bulb from Google Assist on RPi

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-smart-home

I configured Philips Bulb using Google Home Android APP.

I installed Google Assistant SDK on Raspberry Pi 4B by following 
 https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python

 I used same email ID at all places.

 What is a way to control the bulb from RPi?

 Is there a document available explaining the process?

Answer (score 0):

Using voice/text commands of "turn on the bulb" or "change bulb color to red" are the only types of methods to control the device.